# Why <td > height not equal to <img > height inside of it when DOCTYPE is XHTML 1.0 Strict?

Tags: html, html-table, doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>

<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td align="right" colspan="5">
            <span class="validationInline">*</span> 
            <span class="hint">Required fields</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5" background="http://media.monster.com.hk/bgr_8.gif">
            <img src="/static/cleardot.gif" height="1" width="1" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Can check it out here:
http://maishudi.com/tt2.html

I've known it's  caused by DOCTYPE ,because deleting that part will make it normal:

http://maishudi.com/tt.html

So what's wrong?How can I make it work with the DOCTYPE ?

Comment: I would, first of all, recommend to replace XHTML1.0 doctype with HTML4.01 strict one (see http://www.webdevout.net/articles/beware-of-xhtml for why this is a good idea)

Comment: Oh I can't,change doctype will cause a lot of other troubles for me now.

Comment: I would recommend you continue to use XHTML Strict.  Stricter requirements are a good thing in absolutely every form of software development except HTML.  That says a lot of what programmers generally think of HTML and the competence of those forced to write it.  What the article from kangax does not say is that it is perfectly valid to send XHTML Strict as text/html.  Only XHTML 1.1 requires the application/xml+xhtml mime type.

Comment: @austin I believe disadvantages of serving xhtml as text/html clearly outweigh its advantages (see, for example, hixie's thorough explanation - http://hixie.ch/advocacy/xhtml). YMMV.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Note: this probably depends on the browser.
The size of block-level element (td, div, etc) if not specified will only be as big as needed, according to the space taken by its content. If specified, it will try to expand accordingly, **except** if the content is bigger, in which case it will expand as necessary.

In your example, the cell contains a single character (the non-breaking space), which take the size of single line. Hence, the block element must be at least 1 line-height high; it can't assume any smaller size. This is why your height declaration was ignored.

You may want to use this style:

```
line-height: 1px;
```

This sets the line-height to 1px. Line-height is not an element, so the above rule doesn't apply.

Comment: Works like charm! But can you explain why height has no effect on td?

Comment: It's based on browsers also. Some browsers expect text content within elements. This can also happen with divs.

Answer (score 13):

Add a style block with this rule

```
td img {display: block;}
```

and see [Images, Tables, and Mysterious Gaps](https://web.archive.org/web/20191007214208/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Misc_top_level/Images,_Tables,_and_Mysterious_Gaps) for a full explanation.

Comment: The link is dead. Now the gaps are forever mysterious.

Comment: @Mentalist - Thankfully, we have the Wayback Machine. Link amended.

Answer (score 0):

background isn't a standard attribute for TD elements is the reason. Instead use:

```
style="background: url(/path/to/image.png);"
```

As for your 1 pixel image, I assume this is simply to make the table cell appear? If so, that's not the advised way of doing it. You can either do:

```
table { empty-cells: show; }
```

in CSS although I don't think IE6 supports that. The more standards compliant way is to use a non breaking space:

```
<td>&nbsp;</td>
```